# Is there any Mistake in my angular code?No Errors, but I also am not able to display placeholder as well as the default selection for the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to achieve a simple dropdown using ng-select, I am trying to fix the problem for the past many days but I cannot get hang of it. if anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

dropdown.ts

```
    formGroup = new FormGroup({
...
    videotype: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  ..
});

...
  ngOnInit()
   { 
   videotype = [
      { id: "First", name: "First" },
      { id: "Second", name: "Second" },
      { id: "Third", name: "Third" },
      { id: "Forth", name: "Forth" },
  ];
  }
```

dropdown.html

```
    <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 form-group">
              <label> {{ "Something.VideoType" | translate }}</label>
              <ng-select
               [items]="videotype"
               bindLabel="name"
               bindValue="id"
               placeholder="Select Appropriate Option"
               formControlName="videotype"
               labelForId="First"
               [(ngModel)]="Something.videotype"
                >
            </ng-select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is `something.videotype` ?

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-uqxvdy

Comment: @JoharZaman that is the way I connect my Component and its model file for sending and receiving data from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `formGroup` in the template. Also, we should not use `formControlName` and `ngModel` together because it doesn't make any sense.

Here is the working example with formGroup using the default value:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ysqkv?file=src/bindings-default-example.component.html

**UPDATE**

I have update the above example to set the formGroup value in `OnInit` of the component to show how you can set the value of `ng-select`.

Comment: I do have added formGroup in the template, as the dropdown(ng-select) is part of a form so it is inside many elements from fromGroup. and when I remove the formControlName from the ng-select console throws me this error   "ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead."

Comment: Did you check the example I had in the answer?

Comment: @yeshabhatt why you do need to have `ngModel` with the formControlName?

Comment: yes, I did check and tried, after that I replied. to give you a brief idea,  I am using the same component for adding data and editing data. so when I edit data I fetch values that I already entered for the component. so to set to the input field (and also here ng-select) I am using ngModel.

Comment: when you will fetch the values then you can do this to set the value for dropdown like this: `this.formGroup.controls["videotype"].setValue("First");`